# How to get access of the state tree in effects? (@ngrx/effects 2.x)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am updating [@ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects) from 1.x to 2.x

In 1.x I have access of state tree in effect:

```
  constructor(private updates$: StateUpdates<AppState>) {}

  @Effect() bar$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(Actions.FOO)
    .map(obj => obj.state.user.isCool)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .filter(x => x)
    .map(() => ({ type: Actions.BAR }));
```

Now in 2.x, it only gives me action. Is there still a way to get access of the state tree? Or should I avoid using like this because it is not a good practice?

```
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}

  @Effect() bar$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ActionTypes.FOO)
    .map((obj: any) => {
      console.log(obj);              // here is action only
      return obj.state.user.isCool   // so it is wrong here
    })
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .filter(x => x)
    .map(() => ({ type: ActionTypes.BAR }));
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Another way is using `.withLatestFrom(this.store)`. So the complete code is:

```
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {}

 @Effect() bar$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ActionTypes.FOO)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store, (action, state) => state.user.isCool)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .filter(x => x)
    .map(() => ({ type: ActionTypes.BAR }));
```

Comment: Also, if you use `this.store.select(fromRoot.getUserIsCool)` you don't have to use `distinctUntilChanged()`... right?

Comment: Passing the store to `withLatestFrom` throws `TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`. It does work though. Any idea why I get the error?

Comment: It works for me and saving my day.Thanks! Could you explain a bit about the action where the "withlastestFrom" receive? it just shows type "never" in my code

Answer (score 5):

Effects don't have to be class properties; they can be methods, too. Which means you can access a store that's injected into the constructor.

*At the time of writing this answer, the semantics of property declarations and* `public`/`private` *constructor parameters were not clear to me. If properties are declared after the constructor, they can access the* `public`/`private` *members declared via constructor parameters - so you don't have to declare your effects as functions.*

With the injected store, you should be able to use an operator like `mergeMap` to get the state and combine it with the update you received:

```
@Effect()
bar$(): Observable<Action> {

  return this.actions$
    .ofType(ActionTypes.FOO)
    .mergeMap((update) => this.store.first().map((state) => ({ state, update })))
    .map((both) => {
      // Do whatever it is you need to do with both.update and both.state.
      return both.update;
    })
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .filter(x => x)
    .map(() => ({ type: ActionTypes.BAR }));
  }
}
```

Whether or not doing this is good practice is a matter of opinion, I guess. Reading the state - ideally by composing an ngrx-style selector - sounds reasonable, but it would be cleaner if all of the information you needed for a particular effect was included in the action to which it was listening.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I tested what I'd written - off the top of my head - and my app went berserk, as `combineLatest` resulted in cycle of state updates. Added a comment re: good practice, too.

Comment: thank you so much! Your first try is on the right direction, need change to `withLatestFrom `

Comment: Yep, `withLatestFrom` is a much better solution.