# How to access parameters in an ngrx effect in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a http service call that requires two parameters when dispatched:

```
@Injectable()
export class InvoiceService {
  . . .

  getInvoice(invoiceNumber: string, zipCode: string): Observable<Invoice> {
    . . .
  }
}
```

How do I subsequently pass those two parameters to `this.invoiceService.getInvoice()` in my Effect?

```
@Injectable()
export class InvoiceEffects {
  @Effect()
  getInvoice = this.actions
    .ofType(InvoiceActions.GET_INVOICE)
    .switchMap(() => this.invoiceService.getInvoice())  // need params here
    .map(invoice => {
      return this.invoiceActions.getInvoiceResult(invoice);
    })
}
```

Comment: Presumably, the parameters need to be obtained from the store's state. If that's the case, there's an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565811).

Comment: I'm brand new to ngrx, so please bear with me. In this case, I haven't set any values into the store yet, I'm making a service call to obtain the data I want to store in state. Should I perhaps pass the parameters as the `payload` of my `getInvoice()` action?

Comment: Yep, if you don't have the information in the store and instead the information is source from inputs in a component, for example, putting the information into the payload would be the way to go.

Comment: At least I'm on the right track :) Would you know of an example or documentation on how I can access the payload?

Comment: Regarding examples, I think the best thing to do is spend some time looking through the [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app). It's possible to learn quite a lot by figuring out how it works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can access the payload within the action:

```
@Injectable()
export class InvoiceEffects {
  @Effect()
  getInvoice = this.actions
    .ofType(InvoiceActions.GET_INVOICE)
    .switchMap((action) => this.invoiceService.getInvoice(
      action.payload.invoiceNumber,
      action.payload.zipCode
    ))
    .map(invoice => this.invoiceActions.getInvoiceResult(invoice))
}
```

Or you can use the `toPayload` function from `ngrx/effects` to map the action's payload:

```
import { Actions, Effect, toPayload } from "@ngrx/effects";

@Injectable()
export class InvoiceEffects {
  @Effect()
  getInvoice = this.actions
    .ofType(InvoiceActions.GET_INVOICE)
    .map(toPayload)
    .switchMap((payload) => this.invoiceService.getInvoice(
      payload.invoiceNumber,
      payload.zipCode
    ))
    .map(invoice => this.invoiceActions.getInvoiceResult(invoice))
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Somehow I managed to miss the API docs: https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/docs/api.md It's way too late to be coding. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 9):

In @ngrx/effects v5.0 the utility function `toPayload` was removed, it has been deprecated since @ngrx/effects v4.0.

For Details see: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/commit/b390ef5

Now (since v5.0):

```
actions$.
  .ofType('SOME_ACTION')
  .map((action: SomeActionWithPayload) => action.payload)
```

Example:

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
printPayloadEffect$ = this.action$
    .ofType(fromActions.DEMO_ACTION)
    .map((action: fromActions.DemoAction) => action.payload)
    .pipe(
        tap((payload) => console.log(payload))
    );
```

Before:

```
import { toPayload } from '@ngrx/effects';

actions$.
  ofType('SOME_ACTION').
  map(toPayload);
```